# adding newly created dom elements to an empty jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Why doesn't this work in jQuery 1.4.2?

```
var $list = $([]);
for(var i=0; i<50; i++) {
    $list.add( $('<div/>', { id: 'jake', class: 'test' }).data('test', { hi: 'hello' }) );
}
alert($list.size()); // 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Correct explanation given at : [jQuery add elements to empty selection?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533929/jquery-add-elements-to-empty-selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why `add` doesn't work I don't know, but you can replace it with `push` due to jQuery being an Array-like object, which should do what you want.

Comment: awesome, i thought i tried that too, but apparently not! thanks.

Comment: it looks like in order to use .clone(true) on $list, my $list array needs to be a dom node (eg: $('<div />') but i don't want a containing div, i just want a list of dom nodes with no parent. (like an array!) is that possible?

Comment: it's not the end of the world if i have to have a containing div i guess. it's just extra junk in the dom. oh well.

Comment: In your case, because each div is created separately before being pushed onto $list, each element in $list is actually its own separate jQuery object, so THOSE are what you need to call clone on:

`clones = $list.map(function () { return this.clone(true); });` and you should be good to go.

Comment: and no, you definitely won't need the containing div :)

Answer (score 11):

Pointing back the reference list again works for me;
e.g. **$list** = **$list.add( $('<div/>') )**;

```
var $list = $([]);
for(var i=0; i<50; i++) {
    $list=$list.add( $('<div/>', { 'id': 'jake'+i, 'class': 'test' }).data('test', { hi: 'hello' }) );
}
alert($list.size()); // 50
```

Comment: Upvote for solving my problem, but I wish there was a better way (read: `.append()`) to add items to an empty set. Shog9's answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598494/how-to-create-an-empty-non-null-jquery-object-ready-for-appending) explains why there isn't.