# How to create an empty, non-null jQuery object ready for appending?

Tags: jquery, dom

I want to append some html to an empty non null jQuery object only in the loop but it's not working unless I create an object and add an html tag during creation. How can I create an empty jQuery object and be able to add html to it later on?

```
//var $new = $().add("");  //can't use this object in the loop
//var $new = $([]);        //can't use this object in the loop
//var $new = $();        //can't use this object in the loop
//var $new = $("#nonexistingelement"); //can't use this object in the loop
var $new = $().add("<tr>");  //works but I don't want to add any html at this point. 

$.each(.....)
  {
    $new.append("<sometag>");

});

alert($new.html());  //should display some html
```

**Addition:**
[http://jsfiddle.net/vfPNT](http://jsfiddle.net/vfPNT/)/

Comment: There's a lot of "can't" there, and not much "here's precisely what I saw".

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897331/getting-an-empty-jquery-object. Answer seems to be `$([])` in older versions of jQuery, and `$()` in newer ones. You don't seem to explain why this isn't good enough for you.

Comment: It's not a duplicate! Check the jsfiddle example and notice that $([]) or $() both display null in the alert. I want an empty non null object. Check my post before voting quickly to close. I already mentioned $([]) and $() in the post!

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: In your fiddle, you never created `$new`.

Comment: @Tomalak: I was testing each $new. I updated it. Uncomment each $new and see how each $new behaves. None works the way I want.

Comment: @Tomalak: That's why I posted. Looking for a way to append to an empty object. How to create one? Like appending to an empty string.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. The answers in the other post mention to use $([]). I clearly mentioned this fact in my question and said it can't be used. Duh!

Comment: @Tony: Who said it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find another way so I started with the `<tr>`. Removing the `<tr>` while keeping the contents didn't work properly and that's why I posted the question. So, instead,  I created a new jQuery selection by selecting all the `<sometag>'s which were inside the <tr>` and threw away $new.

```
var $new = $().add("<tr>");  

$.each(.....)
  {
    $new.append("<sometag>");

});
$new.append("</tr>");
$newObject = $('sometagt', $new)
..... do more work using $newObject
```

Answer (score 81):

Your problem here is that there aren't "null" jQuery objects that can't be appended to and "empty" ones that can be. You've already identified several ways to create an empty one, and while there may be more, it doesn't matter - what you're trying to do simply won't do what you expect it to, no matter *how* you start off, because...

...[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) modifies the DOM, not the jQuery object. And an empty jQuery object *has no DOM*! [Tomalak had the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598494/how-to-create-an-empty-non-null-jquery-object-ready-for-appending/5598631#5598631), though you may not have understood it.

I'm going to make three observations about jQuery that you're probably already aware of, but which are useful in understanding the remainder of this answer and therefore may benefit future readers:

1. A jQuery object is fundamentally a *set* of DOM elements.
2. Some jQuery methods operate on the set, and some operate on the nodes *in* the set.
3. Some jQuery methods operate only on (or retrieve information only from) the *first* node added to the set.

With these three observations in mind, let's consider your example:

```
// 1. create an empty set somehow (doesn't matter how)
var $new = $();

// 2. iterate over something
$.each( ..., function( ... )
{
  // 3. construct a DOM fragment from HTML, and append it
  $new.append("<sometag>"); 
});

// 4. try to display HTML corresponding to the jQuery object
alert($new.html());
```

In this example, step #3 will fail to do anything useful because the purpose of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is to take whatever DOM elements it is given and append them as children to each DOM element in the set. Since `$new` is an *empty* set, there are no elements to append to, and... nothing happens. Step #1 is working just fine - but by creating a set without any DOM elements in it, you've set yourself up to fail when you try to use methods that exist to modify the DOM! Reference Observation #2... to modify the set, you need to call a method that actually *operates* on the set.

Ok, so let's say we use the *set modification* method [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) instead:

```
  $new = $new.add("<sometag>");
```

Now we're good, right? Each pass through the loop will create a new jQuery object consisting of the previous set + a newly-created element. Well...

...this will just cause step #4 to do something odd. See, [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is one of those methods I mentioned in Observation #3 - it operates *only on the first element* in the set. So instead of a sequence (`"<sometag><sometag><sometag>..."`) you're only gonna get a HTML representation of the element created on the first pass through the loop (`"<sometag>"`). Except... You're not even going to get *that*, because [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) creates a representation of the element's *children* - so what you're *really* going to end up with is `""`...

This was all just a big disappointment: you started off working with the set (Step #1), then tried to operate on the DOM (Step #3), and finished up by trying to pull data from *one* DOM element (that didn't exist) (and wouldn't have had any data if it did) (Step #4).

[The solution you finally came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598494/how-to-create-an-empty-non-null-jquery-object-ready-for-appending/5835789#5835789) isn't terrible - you're essentially opting to add *one* root element to the set starting out, and operate entirely on this DOM fragment until you're done adding new elements and are ready to operate on them. You've omitted it from your revised example, but `html()` would work too, since it would simply dump the contents of your root element.

But just to be complete, I'll give you a final example that works on the *set*, starting with an empty jQuery object:

```
var $new = $();
$.each( [1, 2, 3, 4], function(i, v)
{
  $new = $new.add("<div>");
});

alert($new.length == 4); // true

// alerts: <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
alert($("<div>").append($new).html());
```

Comment: I think the question is wrong for stating all kinds of problematic solutions instead of focussing on the actual question/problem. I think the chosen answer is also wrong in different ways. I think this answer is really great! You are explaining why it isn't working and what can be the right solution. I ended up on this page and found what I was looking for in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer for question, author asked for empty object for `append`ing, not `add`ing.

Comment: Because `append()` doesn't operate on the jQuery object, @Benio - it operates on the elements contained in the jQuery object. By definition, an empty jQuery object cannot `append()`... Please read the answer above for why and how to do what the asker intends.

Comment: @Shog9 While you explained why it's not possible, giving `add` related code, Justin Geeslin actually provided the correct answer for `append`ing, presenting a **Document Fragment**, which common use is *assembling a DOM subtree within it*, as api docs says.

Comment: Yes, you can successfully use `append()` as long as you first add some other node to the jQuery object, @Benio. As long as the object isn't truly *empty*, it'll do something.

Answer (score 23):

Document Fragments are perfect for this; creates an empty object ready for appending. :)

```
$(document.createDocumentFragment())
```

Comment: $('').add($el) or $().add($el) did not work, but $(document.createDocumentFragment()) worked fine 

Answer (score 1):

Your object `$new` is an empty selector, so `append` has no sets to append to.

`add` is required to add a DOM node, and then you append to those DOM nodes. Don't think you can avoid starting with an `.add`.

Answer (score 1):

i testet the above solution but it did not work for me, it always stayed as empty jQuery object...

if anybody interested, here is my solution:

```
var jQueryElements = [],
    $new;

$.each( [1, 2, 3, 4], function(i, v){
  jQueryElements = jQueryElements.push($('<div>').get(0));
});

$new = $(jQueryElements);
```

Comment: `push` returns the new length of the array, so you don't want to assign that to `jQueryElements`.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to end up with an ugly  tag:

```
if(!$new){
$new.append("</sometag>");
} else {
var $new = $("</sometag>");
```